What is the missing fifth of the missing fifths?
I've gotten into the NYT connections puzzles recently, where as you know the goal is to sort 16 words into four groups of four. Here is one:











one
log seven
he
had


little
she
lamb
pi


root two
mystère
mad apple
mary


we
kà
phi
you



https://connectionsplus.io/game/Yf33vR
But the final answer I'm looking for is a single letter than answers this question:  what is the missing fifth of the missing fifths?

The missing letter is:

U!


The groups are:

 

So

Each group can have another letter added:

- 'a' for nursery rhyme
- 'e' for irrational numbers
- 'i' for pronouns
- 'o' for cirque de soleil

And of course, these are

the vowels, with 'u' missing!


Ah, just beat me to it!

@Deusovi only got one one hand to type with atm, so glad I got there :P
